# Change navigationbar color & title color on different screens

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar

In my iPhone app, I have two NavigationC0ntroller background color and Title color

1. White color Background + Red Color Title
2. Clear color Background + White color title

I am using a common code as below for changing background color & Title color

```
@objc class Helper : NSObject{
class func restNavigationBarWithNavigationController(navigationController : UINavigationController , withColor : UIColor,isTranslucent : Bool )
{
    navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = isTranslucent
    navigationController.view.backgroundColor = withColor
    navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = withColor
}
}
```

I am calling above in viewdidload & ViewWIllAppear of view controllers as below

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white

Helper.restNavigationBarWithNavigationController(navigationController: 
self.navigationController!, withColor: .clear, isTranslucent: true)
```

But above code does not work If I pop a screen from White color to Red color title & Vice Versa.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Any Idea or suggestoin would be great. (FYI: I am using same code base in Objective-c viewcontrollers)

Comment: I think you try this Helper().restNavigationBarWithNavigationController(navigationController: 
self.navigationController!, withColor: .clear, isTranslucent: true)

Comment: Here you are not initialising your class, First initialise your class and then call your function with that class reference Or simply do this Helper().restNavigationBarWithNavigationController(navigationController: self.navigationController!, withColor: .clear, isTranslucent: true)

Comment: I am calling above class method from my viewcontrollers ViewDidLoad/ViewWIllAppear. Please let me know what do you mean by 'not initialising your class'

Comment: As per my understanding, you code is running proper while showing new screen with color, but when you pop that screen previous screen navigation bar color not show proper. If this is your question then while pop screen in that screen remove color which you selected in viewWillDisapper()

Answer (score 6):

Well, if you want to change navigation bar style in each screens, you can use this following code :

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // White color Background + Red Color Title
        navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
        navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
    }
}
```

// Next

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Clear color Background + White color title
        navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear
        navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }
}
```

This works in Swift 4

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 separates the `NSAttributedStringKey` type into `NSAttributedString.Key` and is used as below (Swift 5.1.3).

```
func configureNavigationBar() {
      navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .darkGray
      navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
 }
```